# Netbeans IDE - Download one file from thousands in one directory

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

[[Question Updated for Clarity]]

I am using the Netbeans IDE.

I have created a PHP Project within the IDE and wish to download files that are on my server so that they can be edited in my local envirionment.

Once connected to the server, the Netbeans GUI presents me with a directory listing with checkboxes to select which files to download.

In one of these directories on the server, there is a single file - that I know the name of - nestling amongst thousands of other files in the same directory.

I want to download just this one file to my local Netbeans environment, but it seems that in order to do so, Netbeans has to list all these thousands of files, even though I only want the one file.

Is there a quicker way or a bypass I am missing.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the content of the files relevant to the question?

Comment: This is not a Java question, it a Netbeans IDE question.

Comment: But ***how*** do you download that file? Update your post to detail ***the exact steps*** you go through, in enough detail that we can attempt a similar procedure. As it stands your question is too vague.

Comment: I see your point. I'll see if I can clarify.  Updating the question.